# Is it possible to reorder django fields with rest api (getting the new order with requests)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model like this (hypothetical):

```
class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      last_name = models.CharField()
      age = models.IntegerField()
```

I access this with an API call so I get the json `{name: "John", last_name: "Doe", age: 20}` and show this as an ordered list like this

1. John
2. Doe
3. 20

I want to reorder this list by dragging the elements (that's easy with [this](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc)) but once saved and reloaded the data returns to original order because the order isn't saved. Is there a way to achieve this? The best I can think of is getting a new field `fields_order` that keeps the fields names with the specified order but I think that should be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

we handle this issue by defining an index field with an integer type that is like a point for any object, after that with use of Meta class in model class, the object's ordered with this field

```
Class UModel(models.Model):
    .
    .
    index = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
         ordering = ('-index',)
```

Comment: This is useful to reorder the objects from the query but I mean reordering the fields of one object.